# Firebase cloud messaging integration in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase push notifications but when the app is in open, the notification does not come in.

This is my FirebaseService class

```
class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    init {
        Log.d("TAG", "onMessageReceived: ")
    }
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.d("TAG", "onNewToken: $token")
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        Log.d("TAG", "onMessageReceived: ${message.notification?.title}")
    }
}
```

I have also added this class to my manifest as shown below

```
<service
    android:name=".FirebaseService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGIN_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

However, when the app is in the background, I receive a notification on the notification tray but when the app is open, I expect to see the log message in the onMessageReceived method which never triggers.

What am I missing?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).